# PowerQuery: Join Two Tables by Aligning them (not duplicating values from Table 1)

Tags: join, merge, alignment

I'm trying to merge two tables together:
Table 2 needs to be placed right next to Table 1, and both have a common 'ID' that is duplicated:

[Table 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0dj2a.png)

[Table 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUJrH.png)

[Desired Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5CHIW.png)

I tried a "Join" and an "Alignment", and "Group By" but they seemed to either duplicate the Table 1 values, or generally not add all the Table 2 values.